# how to output a specific category

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, blogs

I have a rails 3 blog app which have article and category in `has_many` and `belongs_to association`,  i have a lot of category like sport news , entertaiment news etc but i want on my views only sportnews to show, i mean articles that has the category of sport to show and i want it to show on my application.html.erb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations
  has_one  :payment
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :image, :description

   mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

Comment: please the code in this my question is not similer to what i want i just use it so stackoverflow can let me post

Comment: "the code in this my question is not similer to what i want i just use it so stackoverflow can let me post"? FAIL! Show the code that relates to your question. What sense does it make to use unrelated code, and what good does it do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your associations defined like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Then getting all "sportnews" articles is as simple as: (this goes into your controller)

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @sportnews_category = Category.where(name: "sportnews").first
    @sportnews_articles = @sportnews_category.articles
  end
end
```

or:

```
@sportnews_category = Category.where(name: "sportnews").first
@sportnews_articles = Article.where(category_id: @sportnews_category)
```

You could even define a scope:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  scope :sportnews, includes(:category).where(category: {name: "sportnews"})
end

@sportnews_articles = Article.sportnews
```

Then in your `index.html.erb` view something like:

```
<% @sportnews_articles.each do |article| %>
  <h1><%= article.title %></h1>
  <p><%= article.content %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @OnozorObogbareAlex I've added the view part

Comment: no i have define the scope i want it to show on my views and i also wnt to limit by 5 (thanks stefan)

Comment: just add `limit(5)`, e.g. `Article.sportnews.limit(5)`

Comment: BTW, all these topics are covered in the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org)

Comment: am getting undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: well this is my model  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :type_id, :name, :content, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remote_avatar_url, :category_id
  validates_presence_of :name, :content 
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :category 
 def to_param
    [id, name.parameterize].join("-")
  end
  scope :sportnews, includes(:category).where(category: {name: "sportnews"})
  @sportnews_articles = Article.sportnews
end

Comment: That means `@sportnews_articles` is `nil`. You have to set this variable in your controller.

Comment: well how do i set it in my controller please dont be angry with my questions

Comment: hello waht do i do now please help

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please read the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), all these basic steps are well explained.